# UIRefreshControl's tintColor can't be initially set

Tags: swift, scrollview, ios13, uirefreshcontrol, tintcolor

I'm currently struggling with a problem that I couldn't handle and I wasn't able to find any answer or workarounds.

The problem is that I want to change color for the refreshControl to .white for example, I call the `beginRefreshingManually()` function in every viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad()` but the initial color is still black. When trying to manually pull to refresh the Refreshcontrol becomes .white

Here's some of the code I've wrote:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func setupRefreshControl(withTintColor tintColor: UIColor = JDColorConstants.UIScrollView.refreshControlWhiteColor.color,
                             completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.tintColor = tintColor
        refreshControl.addAction(forEvent: .valueChanged, closure: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + JDDurationConstants.shortAnimationDuration) {
                completion()
            }
        })

        self.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
}

extension UIRefreshControl {
    func beginRefreshingManually() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let scrollView = UIApplication.shared.topViewController()?.getScrollView() else { return }
            let constant = UIApplication.shared.getTopHeightOfSafeArea() +
                (UIApplication.shared.topViewController()?.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height ?? 0) +
                (self?.frame.height ?? 0)
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -constant), animated: true)
            self?.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
            self?.beginRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Same here. Any ideia?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try call manually beginRefreshingManuall method in viewDidLoad ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //it will react as if you were being renewed with your hand
        yourUIRefreshControl.beginRefreshingManually()
    }
```